# Add and read a json file in the iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsbundle

I have created a simple Xcode 4.2 project with a empty view controller.
I added a json file to this project (i not had a resouces folder/group and so i 
have create these resouces folder and group).
So, in my iphone simulator i can read this json file correctly.
When i have tested my example app on my device I had a error: i can't read the 
json file: Why?
I use this simple code lines:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME ofType:CONFIGURATION_FILE_TYEPE]; 
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
```

Comment: No no...
on the device, it is as if the file does not exist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved...
in my code the **CONFIGURATION_FILE_TYEPE** is a define ***@"JSON"***..
i have changed this with ***@"json"***.. this work well on device and simulator!

Comment: Yes. By default Mac OSX is case insensitive and iOS Simulator use the same file system of the Mac operating system.
iOS Devices uses a case sensitive file-system, so it could happen (often with images) issues like yours.